# Preventing a single app from updating from Play Store

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates

I have a single app (ES File Explorer) that I want to prevent from updating and I don't quite understand what is happening.

1. Removed the app from My Apps in the Play Store
2. Turned off my network connection
3. Uninstalled the new version
4. Side loaded the old version
5. Immediately unchecked the auto update within the app  (maybe about 30 sec later)
6. Turned my network back on

If I now check My Apps, there is an update for the app waiting and if I turn auto update back on, it will update to the new version.

If the app is not listed on My Apps - All (and I rechecked) and auto update is turned off within the app, what is causing this app to update and how do I prevent it?

Comment: By "auto update within the app", did you mean the one on ES File Explorer? Have you also unchecked the auto-update on Play Store? (From Play Store, go to ES File Explorer's page, open the overflow menu (3-dot) on the upper right)

Comment: Please see this new article 2017/02/10 [10 most useless apps and games for Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/most-useless-apps-android-749163). Most prominent, but specifically named in the list: ES File Explorer (along with quote-Booster apps, Anti-Virus apps, and Task Killers-unquote)

Comment: @wbogacz That's why they want to prevent it from updating

Comment: I've tried using Titanium Backup "Detach from Market" but it still shows up again later.  Re-signing the package is supposed to work, but when I tried that, the app broke. https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/permanently-stop-any-app-from-updating-play-store-no-computer-needed-0184063/

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this by making the app Immutable ? I tried to make the base.apk immutable in /data/apk/, but the new update gets installed on a different folder, with a different unique ID

Answer (score 7):

Self sign the application that you don't want to be updated. If the signatures are different then for security reasons the app will never be updated.

Check this [article](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/permanently-stop-any-app-from-updating-play-store-no-computer-needed-0184063/) to know how you can perform this within your smartphone.

Comment: 1) Get the apk of the app you want to resign 2) Resign the apk via an app e.g [apk-signer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haibison.apksigner) (This app has an option to do steps 1 and 2 in one go by selecting sign an app - but I didn't try it since I already had the apk). 3) Uninstall the original app 4) install the newly signed app via the new apk 5) Completely close Google play store and open it again it should no longer offer to update the app at all.

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer good job @Sparkzz

Comment: Doesn't work with all apps

Answer (score 6):

If you search the app on Play Store and open the app detail page you'll see three dots on upper-left corner (overflow menu).

Click on it. Then uncheck 'Auto-update'

[image: Play store screenshot]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

Comment: This setting is updated along with global Play Store auto-update setting, so it's no use, it cannot be regulated individually.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, APK-signer is no more usable (it sends you to create an account, verify it with VISA, and watch ads to add points to unlock the "free" feature)

BTW, I found APK Explorer & Editor on F-Droid:

1. Install & run it
2. Select installed APK you want to remove from PlayStore.
3. Hammer icon -> Prepare a signed APK
4. Create & note the path where it's created
5. Uninstall your app
6. Reinstall from modified APK
   The app is no more present on the Play Store.

Comment: Thank you very much - after being forcibly updated by Google multiple times, this finally saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for this:
[**Update Locker**](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/mod-xposed-4-1-update-locker-stop-update-your-apps.4433253/)

Needs Xposed

[Direct link to the module](https://forum.xda-developers.com/attachments/updatelocker_v1-2-2-apk.5747667/)
But don't skip the instructions from the link above

Answer (score -1):

Initially, I unchecked auto update both within the app and in the Play Store. I still got the update.

I then removed the app from My Apps, uninstalled, reinstalled the APK, quickly unchecked the auto-update box. I can no longer uncheck it in the Play Store as I have removed the app from the list.

I do not get an auto-update, but there is an update waiting for me to click on the update button. Since I removed it from the Play Store and uninstalled the app from my device and reinstalled the old APK from a flash drive, how does Google know to send me an update?

I am afraid that at some point I will forget and click on the update all button.

Comment: Play Store regularly scans all apps (by comparing the package name) on the device, including one that is installed from APK.

Answer (score -2):

Well, turning auto update off shall prevent the update. Though there is another way of doing it:

1. Uninstall the app.
2. Download and install the apk from any website other than playstore.
3. Now you are good to go!

Playstore now shouldn't list your app under the installed app section. So, no more updates!

Hope it helps.

Comment: Afraid ~24h later Playstore picks it up again and the update will be back. Doesn't matter you've installed it from a different source, it does so even with pre-installed apps.